# How can I call a Go function from Java using the Java native interface?

Tags: java, go, jna

It is possible to call C methods through the [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) interface in Java. How can I reach the same functionality with Go?

```
package main

import "fmt"

import "C"

//export Add
func Add(x, y int) int {
    fmt.Printf("Go says: adding %v and %v\n", x, y)
    return x + y
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to call your "Add" function from java? I'm really confused, because that code you just posted is GO, not java, maybe if that is in fact the goal post the java code you've tried to use to access this function?

Comment: @zack6849 hes trying to use JNA, there is a tag but its not specified in the question body.

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf) seems to be a relatively recent article on the topic. I have not verified its content though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it displays no attempt to do even a minimal research and does not present a clear narrow problem.

Comment: Yes, I need to move some logic from Java 'Spring Batch'  to Golang, in order to improve the performance. My idea is use JNA as Interface to access to Golang functions.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After review of the documentation about [Go Shared Libraries](https://github.com/jbuberel/buildmodeshared):

It is possible to integrate the call of Go functions from Java Spring Batch. Below is a short example:

Go function:

```
package main

import "fmt"

import "C"

//export Add
func Add(x, y int) int {
    fmt.Printf("Go says: adding %v and %v\n", x, y)
    return x + y
}
```

After that, execute the command to generate the binary files:

```
go build -buildmode=c-shared -o bin/lib-cqm-transformer.so src/cqm_transformer.go
```

This generates the binary files:

```
ls -la bin/
total 2860
drwxrwxr-x 2 dmotta dmotta    4096 abr 23 01:13 .
drwxrwxr-x 5 dmotta dmotta    4096 abr 23 00:35 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root      1558 abr 23 01:13 lib-cqm-transformer.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root   2915112 abr 23 01:13 lib-cqm-transformer.so
```

Finally, create the JNA class:

```
package com.XX.XX.batch.engine.transformer;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class GoEngineTransformerTest {
  static GoCqmTransformer GO_CQM_TRANSFORMER;
  static {
    String os = System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase();
    String libExtension;
    if (os.contains("mac os")) {
      libExtension = "dylib";
    } else if (os.contains("windows")) {
      libExtension = "dll";
    } else {
      libExtension = "so";
    }

    String pwd = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String lib = pwd + "/golang/bin/lib-cqm-transformer." + libExtension;
    GO_CQM_TRANSFORMER = (GoCqmTransformer) Native.loadLibrary(lib, GoCqmTransformer.class);
  }

  public interface GoCqmTransformer extends Library {
    long Add(long x, long y);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Java says: about to call Go ..");
    long total = GO_CQM_TRANSFORMER.Add(30, 12);
    System.out.println("Java says: result is " + total);
  }
}
```

After that, execute from the main Java class. Results:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: You have loaded library /tmp/jna1412558273325390219.tmp which might have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
Java says: about to call Go ..
Go says: adding 30 and 12
Java says: result is 42
```