# Calling Golang from Java using JNI on Windows leads to "A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed"

Tags: java, windows, go, java-native-interface, mingw-w64

I created the following example project to test out calling Golang code from Java using JNI: https://github.com/blaubaer/golang-jni

When I call `build.cmd` I receive an error message like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: [...]\out\hello.dll: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2430)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2487)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2684)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2649)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:829)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1867)
        at Hello.<clinit>(Hello.java:3)
```

Used environment:

- Windows: 10.0.17763, Build 17763, 64bit
- Golang: 1.11.5, windows/amd64
- Java: 11.0.2 2019-01-15 LTS, 64-Bit
- MinGW-w64: x86_64-8.1.0-win32-sjlj-rt_v6-rev0

Thanks!

Comment: See [How to call go function from java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49986729/how-to-call-go-function-from-java)

Comment: Also: [Calling Go Functions from Other Languages](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/calling-go-functions-from-other-languages-4c7d8bcc69bf)

Comment: Thanks for your input. But this stuff is using JNA which is not my issue. I need a solution for JNI because JNA is for my purpose too slow.

Comment: You can't call arbitrary libraries with JNI. You either need JNA for that or create a wrapper library. See also my answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52308121/including-the-so-library-to-the-java-project-linux/52311702#52311702 or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944462/java-call-function-from-a-dll/52948018#52948018

Comment: Thank you all for the responses. But again: My target is to create a JNI wrapper. So my question still is: What I have to do that my code is valid JNI code in Golang? A attached a project above where it is the task to modify it until it works - with JNI and not JNA. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be related to a bug inside Golang itself. There is currently a Pull Request opened [runtime: This change modifies Go to fix c-shared dll crash on x64 windows #30944](https://github.com/golang/go/pull/30944) where I can approve that this will fix the issue.